# Detect user is about to log in in Windows 7/8

Tags: windows, winapi, authentication

I need to write a little windows service that should detect when a user is attempting to log in and deny access according to certain criteria, like the hour.

So, I researched the way the Windows Family Safety works when a child has hour restriction, and I noticed that the message received by the user(child) is similar or identical to the one received when a restriction is set using

> net user User /time:etc, etc.

so I suspect that's what the Family Safety use.

However, I would like to interact with the "net" command programatically, and besides that I would like to know if there's an event to watch for when a user is attempting to login, or the user has just logged in.

Which Windows API should I look for to get this functionality?

Comment: You can call "net" programmatically from C# via Process.Start or from C/C++ via ShellExecute/CreateProcess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "net user" commands are available programmatically through the Network Management API. As an example, you can use the `NetUserSetInfo` function along with the `USER_INFO_1020` structure to set the times during which a user can log on.